# how to bold text in class file in android?

Tags: android

```
 String  _body = "sq Home : "+HomeScreen.edt_sqft_home.getText().toString() +"\n"
                        +"Age of Home years : "+HomeScreen.edt_age.getText().toString() +"\n"
                        +"Additional service : "+HomeScreen.output +"\n\n"
                        +"Street Name : "+HomeScreen.edt_streetname.getText().toString() +"\n"
                        +"City : "+HomeScreen.edt_city.getText().toString() +"\n"
                        +"State : "+HomeScreen.edt_state.getText().toString();
```

hiii i want to bold text which is in "". like "Sq Home","Age of Home Years".
how is it posible?? plz help me

Comment: Do you want to capitalize first alphabet of every word? (Since you are talking about "sq Home"==>"Sq Home")

Comment: no,i want to bold only which is shown in red color.. like sq Home :  want to bold ?how is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

```
String source = "This is example text";
Spannable out = new SpannedString(source);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
StyleSpan boldSpan2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
out.setSpan(boldSpan, 1, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
out.setSpan(boldSpan2, 9, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is going to be shown in a TextView you can use HTML tags.
In your case you only have to do this:

```
String _body = "<b>sq Home</b>: " + HomeScreen.edt_sqft_home.getText().toString() + "<br/>"
       + "<b>Age of Home years</b>: " + HomeScreen.edt_age.getText().toString() + "<br/>"
       + "<b>Additional service</b>: " + HomeScreen.output + "<br/><br/>"
       + "<b>Street Name</b>: " + HomeScreen.edt_streetname.getText().toString() + "<br/>"
       + "<b>City</b>: " + HomeScreen.edt_city.getText().toString() + "<br/>"
       + "<b>State</b>: " + HomeScreen.edt_state.getText().toString();

TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(_body));
```

Where `yourTextView` is the view of your Activity that displays the HTML string.

Mark Murphy wrote a post with the [HTML tags supported by TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).